# Manipulation of calculus notation

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to get my calculus back up to scratch after not using it for 20 odd years. During my research, I've just seen this on https://physics.info/kinematics-calculus/:

$$a = \frac{dv}{dt}$$

$$dv = a\ dt$$

$$\int_{v_0}^v dv = \int_0^{\Delta t} a\ dt$$

Is this a valid manipulation of the calculous notation? My understanding is that the d/dt syntax is just notational, so I'm surprised to see it being treated as if the dt and dv where just algebraic variables that can be manipulated in this way.

Specifically, multiply both side by $dt$ is a surprise. Supposing for example we had this:

$$a = \frac{d}{dt}\ f(x)$$

Now, if I do the same thing as above, I get this:

$$d\ f(x) = a\ dt$$

Which looks like nonsense.

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: It is valid through the chain rule

Comment: I've updated the question to better explain my source of confusion

Comment: Are you basically just asking whether it is sensible to multiply by $dt$
"?

Comment: Well, if I can multiple through by it, then I should also be able to do anything else with it that I can do with a variable, right? Such as take a square root. So my question is really aimed at understanding if that's really valid mathematically, and what the limits are when manipulation this notation.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine, mostly. Infinitesmals are really defined under any number system, even when one considers proffs in calculaus/analysis, one deals with epsilon-delta proofs that skirt arounf the issue of infinitesmals.

*Mathematically* however, that is treating those quantities as manipulated 'variables' one could write $dy=f'(x)dx$ as the mathematical definisiont of the infinitesmal $dy$ as the differential is the infinitesmal difference between two successive values of a fucntion.

What is also required is a consideration of the idea of a *separable equation*, namely, that $dy$ and $dx$ are just notation here. And, more importantly, they are not necessary for separation of variables.

A separable equation is of the form
$$g(y)y′=f(x)$$

Comment: I disagree that the infinitesimal distance between two points is a "mathematical definition" of what $dx$ means. I have never seen such a definition but would be happy to be shown one.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, don't do it and it doesn't make sense. You are safe in treating it is just a heuristic that works to simplify some calculations. Since it isn't a defined  operation (unless the author has defined exactly what it means somewhere else), you can rewrite arguments without using it.

There is a framework, namely differential geometry, where these operations are given meaning, but it involves learning a whole new language - that of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).